# Do I have to generate two RSA keys for a server client connection?

Tags: c#, tcp, server, client, rsa

I created a TCP Chat-Server in C# with an login-system,
but i don't know how i have to encrypt messages.
My idea is to send to all clients different public keys and from the side of the clients a new public key to the server, so that both sides can send encrypted messages.

Is this an option or do I have some safety problems here?

Comment: You may like to investigate SslStream()

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt messages? Is the server trusted to have access to the plaintext messages? If so, you can simply use TLS to encrypt the network traffic. If not, you probably need to implement end-to-end security which is much harder.